# Is there a way to test the results of an os.system() command in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.9, os.system

This is not an exact copy of my code, but it's the only idea I have regarding going about this:

```
import os
import re

while True:
    com = input()

    if com == "break":#Doesn't matter
        break

    run = os.system(com)
    if run == "'" + com + "' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.":
        print("Error.")
    else:
        os.system(com)
```

And it doesn't work.  I simply need a way to know if there's a way to test whether an os.system() function works, print the response if it does, and print "Error." otherwise.
If it matters, I'm using python 3.9

Comment: Why are you running the command twice if the first run doesn't produce the expected error? And what exactly isn't working? Note that `os.system` does *not* return any output (either standard error or standard output), but rather the exit status of the command. (At least, in Unix. I'm not sure what Windows considers the "return value" of a command.)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I think you could prove that it works by asserting that the return value is 0. If your goal is to throw an error on an error, why not use a try catch block?

Comment: In general, the `subprocess` module is preferred over using `os.system`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of the `os.system` function is the return the operating system program (or command) does. Conventionally, it is `0` in case of success and a a number different from `0` if it fails. The error message that you want is not the result of the command, but what is sent to `stderr` (typically).

Thus, your code should be:

```py
import os
import re

while True:
    com = input()

    if com == "break":#Doesn't matter
        break

    ret_value = os.system(com)
    if ret_value != 0:
        print(f"Error. Command returned {ret_value}")
    else:
        print("Command returned success")
```